# Simple bash script prints command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

I'm working on an Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to run a **very** simple bash script named print_test:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 123
```

I have the $PATH variable set correctly (it includes the /bin directory) and I have tested that
I'm using the correct line ending (wc -l print_test results in 2). I have changed the permissions using
chmod +x print_test. When I try to run the script I get:

```
print_test: command not found
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Note: when I simply run echo 123 in the terminal it does prints 123 .
Thanks!

Comment: Show in your question (no comment) how you start the script, show full path to your script and add output of `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: where is the script located? if it is in current directory, try `./print_test`

Comment: With a SHEBANG you need to ```chmod +x```. Without you can source or execute it with a interpreter of your choice ( sh/zsh/ash/dash/bash ) in front of your scriptname. Myself personaly like to source whats wanted. Especialy scripts that only defining functions. So try this: ```. yourscriptname```

Comment: Indeed ./print_test worked.  Why is the "./" needed? Why being in the script directory and running "print_test" isn't enough?

Comment: Because the execution of scripts in current directory should not be allowed for security reasons. Therefore PATH environment never ever including: ```./``` For personaly scripts or executables you can ```mkdir ~/bin``` expand your PATH with it and move your scripts there. Dont forget to log off and login so new PATH is working.

Comment: @MRm see [Why do we use “./” (dot slash) to execute a file in Linux/UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path is set properly it must work

**Easier way** , to invoke a shell script

```sh
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Here replace script with the name of your script

Use this at the first line of your script

```
#!<path/to/bash>
```